# Transition matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that we have the following transition matrix with transition states $\mathcal{X}=\left\{0,1,2,3\right\}$

$P:= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1/4 & 3/4 & 0 \\ 3/4 & 0 & 1/4 & 0 \\ 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\ 0&0&1&0  \end{bmatrix} $

I try to calculate the eigenvalues but Im stuck . I found the characteristic polynomial $(\lambda -1)(\lambda^{3}+\frac{3}{4}\lambda^{2}+\frac{1}{16}\lambda-\frac{3}{64})=(\lambda-1)(\lambda^{2}(\lambda+\frac{3}{4})+\frac{1}{16}(\lambda-\frac{3}{4}))$.

But what should I do next in order to find find the roots of the $(\lambda^{2}(\lambda+\frac{3}{4})+\frac{1}{16}(\lambda-\frac{3}{4}))$?

Comment: Why do you need to find the eigenvalues? Their exact forms look horrendous: https://goo.gl/1JCPpd

Comment: I want to calculate the following limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}[X_{n}=3|X_{0}=3]$ and in order to do that I think that I have to calculate the eigenvalues , but as you mentioned it's pretty hard.

Comment: Can you write that limit in matrix form? I don't remember what these symbols mean.

Comment: You mean  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P^{n}_{3,3}$ ??

Comment: Do you mean $=(P_{3,3})^n$? What is $P_{3,3}$?

Comment: Yes the n-th power of transition matrix P and we want at 3,3 , exactly what you wrote.

Comment: So you mean $(P^n)_{3,3}$?

Comment: Yes I mean $(P^{n})_{3,3}$

Comment: I had a type in the WA query above. It should have been [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0,+1%2F4,+3%2F4,+0%7D,+%7B3%2F4,+0,+1%2F4,+0%7D,+%7B1%2F4,+1%2F4,+1%2F4,+1%2F4%7D,+%7B0,+0,+1,++0%7D%7D) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either i) use the Horner's method (see [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) for the example of application) or, if you are not bound to calculate by hand, ii) you can use some software (see [online polynomial roots calculator](https://www.mathportal.org/calculators/polynomials-solvers/polynomial-roots-calculator.php)).

i) enables you to compute all the rational roots of a given polynomial with integer coefficients (and also all roots of polynomials with rational coefficients since you can always multiply a polynomial with rational roots with a convenient integer to get a polynomial with integer coefficients). Nevertheless, you will not find the complex roots with this method.

ii) gives you the roots directly but is inconvenient in case you need to write an exam where the use of a software is prohibited

Note: i) is a good method but when you find a root $x_0$ for the $3$rd order polynomial then I suggest to express the original polynomial as a multiple of the linear one,i.e. $(x - x_0)P(x)$, where $P(x)$ must be $2$nd order polynomial. Then use the classical formula for the roots of $2$nd order polynomials involving the discriminant to compute the roots of $P(x)$. The characteristic polynomial you described will be precisely the one with one rational root but two complex roots so you will not be able to compute all the roots with the Horner's method.

Comment: Why misspell Horner's name?  And to answer the question about the limit of the  $3,3$ entry in $P^n$, why not use mathematics?  (Perron-Frobenius, in particular)?

Comment: Corrected the name - thanks for noticing. As far as the second comment is concerned: the original OP's question is about the roots of a given polynomial to which the Perron-Frobenius is rather unrelated. Whether the question should be about the solution of a given limit (as mentioned in the coments below the question) is unnecessary for me to ponder about.